# Turn nested lists into a table Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matrix, nested-lists

sorry for my annoying questions again.

Having a bit of trouble with some code. The task is to write a function that takes a nested list of currency conversions and turn it into a table (I've attached some pictures for clarification)

(could only attach one image, this is the nested list it converts)

[[10, 9.6, 7.5, 6.7, 4.96], [20, 19.2, 15.0, 13.4, 9.92], [30, 28.799999999999997, 22.5, 20.1, 14.879999999999999], [40, 38.4, 30.0, 26.8, 19.84], [50, 48.0, 37.5, 33.5, 24.8], [60, 57.599999999999994, 45.0, 40.2, 29.759999999999998], [70, 67.2, 52.5, 46.900000000000006, 34.72], [80, 76.8, 60.0, 53.6, 39.68], [90, 86.39999999999999, 67.5, 60.300000000000004, 44.64], [100, 96.0, 75.0, 67.0, 49.6]]

I've got the Header column for the table to work fine. 
I'm having issues when I'm trying to iterate over each sublist in the nested list, convert it to a string (and two decimal places) and with a tab between each entry.

the code I've got so far is:

```
def printTable(cur):
list2 = makeTable(cur)
lst1 = Extract(cur)
lst1.insert(0, "$NZD")
lne1 = "\t".join(lst1)
print(lne1)
list=map(str,list2)
print(list2)
for list in list2:
    for elem in list:
        linelem = "\t".join(elem)
        print(linelem)
```

printTable(cur)

(Note: The first function I call and assign to list2 is what generates the data/nested list)
I've tried playing around a bit but I keep coming up with different error messages trying to convert each sublist to a string.

Thank you all for your help!![enter image description here][1]

Comment: it wouldn't let me post an image, heres a url for expected output (  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbE8B.png )

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method;

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

with open("out.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(a)
pd.read_csv("out.csv", header = [col1, col2, col3, col4, col5])
```